# Update default values in HTML form page using flask app

Tags: html, css, flask

So I have a set of HTML forms on the main page of my flask app. The user sets those values and then they go and do stuff after setting the values. I have the default values being displayed like this

[image]

I'm doing that by just having my forms set up with that value entered as seen directly below.

```
Set Start Frequency: <input type="number" name="set_start_freq" min="0" max="9999999999" value="1750e6"> <br>
Set Stop Frequency: <input type="number" name="set_stop_freq" min="0" max="9999999999" value="2250e6"> <br>
```

And that is good for the start, but then a user enters say '20e8' for the value, the app will update it and hold that value, but after refresh it will still say the default instead of what the value actually is. How can I get that to update with each value and stay that way?

In brief: The page loads with the defaults, the user enters their new value and hits the submit button, the page refreshes and the default values are loaded again rather than what the actual values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people in the future, I basically used a work around. I created a second html page and redirected to that after hitting submit. Below is the html form tag now, I used Jinja 2 formatting to pass in values.

```
Set Start Frequency: <input type="number" name="set_start_freq" min="0" max="9999999999" value={{get_start_freq}}> <br>
Set Stop Frequency: <input type="number" name="set_stop_freq" min="0" max="9999999999" value={{get_stop_freq}}> <br>
```